# Cannot open a file in C- Error in opening a file in C

Tags: c, file, readfile

The main function that opens the file is located in "project" directory. Then I have a "cmake-build-bug" directory( located in "project" directory) where is "data.txt" file located. I want to read it, but for some reason it keeps wrinting `Error to open file`. I never understand how to write the correct path to the file. Or is there another problem that gives the error?

```
  FILE *file[2] ;
  char *fileName2 = "data.txt";
    file[1] = fopen(fileName2, "r");
    if (file[1] == NULL){
        printf("Error to open file\n");
    }
        printf("Reading..\n");
  fclose(file[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an IDE (and since you have a `cmake-build-debug` directory then I guess you're using the CLion IDE) the default working directory is seldom what is expected. And for CLion it seems it's not where you currently store the `data.txt` file. (I don't remember the default for CLion.)

Assuming CLion, you need to edit your "Run/Debug Configuration" for the program (menu "Run" and item "Edit Configuration"), and set the "Working Directory" to where you have the `data.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html the first param is a pathname and not a filename as a lot of people believe.
Let's assume that c:\your_ project\a_subfolder\data.txt is the pathname, just remember that \ is an escape char, so I believe in general, when the file is in a different folder, you could try `char *fileName2 = "c:\\your_ project\\a_sub_folder\\data.txt"`

Just keep an eye on the real path of the file. Cmake tends to create folders to put the executable elements in. For example, look at this case where the file was in a local folder and cmake created a copy in the debug folder.

[image]