# Use relative path with fopen

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I am trying to open a file inside the directory via `fopen`.

The absolute path is the following:

```
/home/user/Desktop/project/src/users/login.json
```

The main.c of my application is here:

```
/home/user/Desktop/project/src
```

I have tried the following formats but they don't work (returns NULL pointer and `errno` is 2):

```
FILE *f = fopen("./users/login.json", "rb");
FILE *f = fopen("/users/login.json", "rb");
FILE *f = fopen("login.json", "rb");
FILE *f = fopen("src/login.json", "rb");
FILE *f = fopen("./src/login.json", "rb");
```

The absolute path works instead:

```
FILE *f = fopen("/home/user/Desktop/project/src/users/login.json", "rb");
```

Comment: The a.out is in /home/user/Desktop/project (I have tha same issue if I use Clion)

Comment: @xing I've already tried using `FILE * f = fopen("users/login.json", "rb");` in my main.c (on `/home/user/Desktop/project/src`) but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You can do a `getcwd` (get current working directory) and construct to path from there.

Comment: @xing Does not work

Comment: The path is relative to the current working directory, which is typically the location of the executable. So if the executable is in the `project` directory, then the relative path is "src/users/login.json".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The absolute path of my files I described them in the question. `/home/user/Desktop/project/src/users/login.json` and
`/home/user/Desktop/project/src/main.c` and `/home/user/Desktop/project/a.out`

Comment: `getcwd` may report a path different from what you think.

Comment: On Clion the getcwd result is `/home/user/Desktop/project/src/cmake-build-debug` instead on Terminal is `/home/user/Desktop/project`

Comment: On Terminal `src/users/login.json` it seems to work on Clion instead it does not.

Comment: On the terminal the relative path is `src/users/login.json`. And in Clion, you need to find the setting that controls the current working directory. Every IDE that I've ever used has such a setting, buried somewhere in the debug menus.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59767048/3386109) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `FILE * f = fopen ("src/users/login.json", "rb");` and changing the Clion working directory to `/home/user/project`